# Laravel 8 - can not set morphOne id when using Polymorphic Relationships

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I use `Polymorphic Relationships` of Laravel 8 to declare `Models` like following:

`Item`:

```php
class Item extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'items';
    
    public function costs()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Receive::class, 'cost_item', 'cost_id', 'item_id')
            ->withPivot([
                'id',
                'cost_id',
                'item_id',             
                'sku_id',
                'qty',              
                'price',
            ])
            ->withTimestamps()
            ->using(CostItem::class);
    }
}
```

`Movement`:

```php
class Movement extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'movements';
    
    public function movable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}
```

`Cost`:

```php
class Cost extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'costs';
    
    public function items()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Item::class, 'cost_item', 'cost_id', 'item_id')
            ->withPivot([
                'id',
                'cost_id',
                'item_id',             
                'sku_id',
                'qty',              
                'price',
            ])
            ->withTimestamps()
            ->using(CostItem::class);
    }
}
```

`CostItem`:

```php
class CostItem extends Pivot
{
    protected $table = 'cost_item';
    
    public function movement()
    {
        return $this->morphOne(Movement::class, 'movable');
    }
    
    public function syncMovement()
    {
        $this->movement()->updateOrCreate([], [
            'sku_id' => $this->sku_id,
            'qty' => $this->qty,
            'price' => $this->cost, 
        ]);
    }
    
    protected static function booted()
    {
        static::created(function ($model) {
            $model->syncMovement();
        });
    }
}
```

I use the `created` event in the `CostItem`, I want to sync `CostItem` data to `Movement` when `CostItem` was created. But when I create the `Cost` and `CostItem` like following:

```php
$cost = new Cost;
$cost->number = 'A00001';
$cost->note = 'test';
$cost->save();

$cost->items()->attach($item, [
    'sku_id' => 1,
    'qty' => 10,
    'price' => 100,
]);
```

I always got the error:

```
Next Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'movable_id' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `movements` (`movable_id`, `movable_type`, `sku_id`, `quantity`, `price`, `remaining`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (?, App\Models\ReceiveItem, 1, ?, 100, ?, 2020-12-01 10:27:03, 2020-12-01 10:27:03))
```

How do I fix this issue ? Or I wrote something wrong ?
Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$this->movement()->updateOrCreate()` in the syncMovement method

Comment: @Donkarnash I have changed, but I still got the same error...

Comment: First argument of updateOrCreate is an empty array which means it will always create right?

Comment: @Donkarnash Yes. but in my case, I just create the new CostItem, i did not update it.

Comment: Try `$cost->fresh()->items()->attach(...)`. Since in the code above that line you instantiated $cost = new Cost and $cost->save() return a boolean so the $cost is still holding unpersisted instance. When you try to attach relationship on unperisited instance it will error out as the id is not present

Comment: @Donkarnash It works after I add fresh() !  Thank you very much!

Comment: I have written an answer explaining the reason. You may please mark it as accepted/upvote for the benefit of subsequent visitors especially newbies who can get assured that the provided answer solves the issues in question.

Answer (score 1):

In the below code snippet from your question, `$cost = new Cost` is a new instance which doesn't represent an existing record in the database hence it doesn't have id value `id=null`.

So when you try to update or create a related record via relationship, it will give error.

Since it doesn't have an id any call to create a related record via the relationship will fail.

Get a fresh record from the database for $cost and then make the call to update or create a related record via relationship.

```php
$cost = new Cost;
$cost->number = 'A00001';
$cost->note = 'test';
$cost->save();

$cost->fresh()->items()->attach($item, [
    'sku_id' => 1,
    'qty' => 10,
    'price' => 100,
]);
```